# Uploading file in Flask with only .csv allowed extension

Tags: python, flask, file-upload

I'm creating a form that allows you to upload a .csv file and then on submit, posts the values inside the csv file to the database.

My problem is that I want to be able to use request.files[] to implement a logic check that only accepts .csv extension files for upload, however, I am not able to use request.files[] when trying to open my csv file with `with open(f, 'r')` below.

I get this error: **"Unexpected type(s): (FileStorage, str) Possible type(s): (Union[str, bytes, PathLike[str], PathLike[bytes], int], str)..."**

If I used request.form[], I don't have the error with opening the file, however, then I can't use the "filename" attribute for the logic check as that requires request.**files**[].

Here is my routes file:

```
allowed_extensions = ['csv']

def allowed_file(filename):
    return '.' in filename and \
           filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1].lower() in allowed_extensions

@main.route("/reading_csv", methods=['POST'])
def reading_csv():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        f = request.files['csvfile']
        # logic check
        if not allowed_file(f.filename):
            flash("Only CSV Files Allowed", 'danger')
            return redirect(url_for('main.alloc_summ'))
        # opening file, reading it in, and inserting values to database
        with open(f, 'r') as csv_file:
            csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
            all_values = [tuple(line.values()) for line in csv_reader]

        con = sql.connect('<hidden path url>')
        cur = con.cursor()

        cur.executemany('INSERT INTO allocation_summary \
                        (state, eligible_applicant, recipient, amount, funding_source_id) \
                            VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)', all_values)
        con.commit()

        cur.close()
        con.close()

        flash("Allocations Added Successfully")
        return redirect(url_for('main.alloc_summ'))
```

Here is the HTML:

```
                    <td>
                        <form class="" action="{{url_for('main.reading_csv')}}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                            <input style="margin-bottom: 5px;" type="file" accept=".csv" name="csvfile" value =""> <br>
                            <input style="margin-bottom: 10px;" type="submit" name="" value="Submit">
                        </form>
                    <br>
                    </td>
```

I can't open my file using the "f" variable that holds the requested file.

Is there any work around to this? TIA!!

Answer (score 0):

Use `.save()` method to save your file, don't try to open it

```
f.save(path: str, filename: str)
```

**Upd:**

Read [Flask: How to upload file](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/patterns/fileuploads/#a-gentle-introduction) to understand the basic of multipart handling in Flask

Comment: Hi! I have read that, but it's specific to just uploading a file. My problem is that I also need to be able to open the file to be able to read in the values and insert them into the database. How would I do that with just saving the file and not opening it?

Comment: Save it, then read it. `request.files` stores files in binary, so you won't be able to read that until you convert them to normal text

Comment: Excuse me if this sounds dumb, but I put "f.save(path: str, filename: str)"  before "with open(f, 'r') as csv_file:" and it throws a bunch of syntax errors. Am I suppose to be writing it differently? TIA

Comment: you must provide a path yourself, save a file in this path, then open this path (not the f variable, but path as default) and read it

Comment: My only concern with that logic is that it won't always be that specific file, so I don't wanna hardcode a specific path in.

Comment: Then use a random string (uuid) to give it the name

Answer (score 0):

FileStorage is a file-like object that understands standard reading functions. It corresponds to a temporary file opened in binary mode. So you don't have to open this file again.
In order to be able to read a CSV file, it should be opened in text mode. This results in a contradiction.
The following example should show you one way to meet your requirements.

```
import csv, io

allowed_extensions = ['csv']

def allowed_file(filename):
    return '.' in filename and \
           filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1].lower() in allowed_extensions

@app.route('/upload', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload():
    if request.method == 'POST' and 'csvfile' in request.files:
        f = request.files['csvfile']
        if f.filename != '' and allowed_file(f.filename):
            with io.TextIOWrapper(f) as fp:
                reader = csv.DictReader(fp, delimiter=',')
                values = [tuple(line.values()) for line in reader]
                print(values)
                # ...
    return render_template('upload.html')
```

```
<form class="" action="{{url_for('upload')}}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" accept="text/csv" name="csvfile" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Please keep in mind that a file can become very large and contains data that should be validated before it is included in your database. Perhaps saving the file as @sudden_appearance describes is a more appropriate solution.

Comment: Hi. What will saving help with? As for validation, I will be implementing multiple checks before allowing insertion into the database.

Comment: @Jessica You just have to keep in mind that as long as the process is not completed, the endpoint will block the return. When you save a file, the data could possibly be added in the background. However, this is much more complex to implement.